# mechanism of url parameter passing

Tags: joomla

I have a simple question.
What is the mechanism of URL parameter passing?

Is it the same with GET method?

I am using

```
JRequest::getVar()
```

It could get the parameters from the URL, I am wondering how it works.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JRequest::getVar()` and the rest of the `JRequest` ilk was the Joomla 1.5 (and earlier) way of getting `GET` and `POST` values, in Joomla! 2.5 and newer, JRequest has been superseded by JInput.

If you're working on a Joomla 1.5 or earlier site you can read about [`JRequest`](http://docs.joomla.org/J1.5%3aRetrieving_and_Filtering_GET_and_POST_requests_with_JRequest%3a%3agetVar) on the [Joomla Doc's website](http://docs.joomla.org). Basically `JRequest` provides combined and consistent access to the superglobal arrays `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST` while providing you with tools to filter the user provided values.

If you're working on Joomla 2.5 or later you should use [`JInput`](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput) which supersedes it.